# What's different between what evaluate prints and what it returns?

Tags: tensorflow

I wrote a custom metric for specificity and sensitivity and passed it as a metric to model.compile() . This is the code I wrote(I've copied most of it from tensorflow's website):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

class MulticlassSensitivity(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name='Sensitivity', **kwargs):
        super(MulticlassSensitivity, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positive = self.add_weight(name='tp', shape=(2,), initializer='zeros')
        self.true_negative = self.add_weight(name='tn', shape=(2,), initializer='zeros')
        self.false_positive = self.add_weight(name='fp', shape=(2,), initializer='zeros')
        self.false_negative = self.add_weight(name='fn', shape=(2,), initializer='zeros')
        self.sensitivity = self.add_weight(name='sensitivity', shape=(2,), initializer='zeros')
        
        self.true_class = tf.Variable([False, True])
        self.false_class = tf.Variable([True, False])
        
    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        threshold = tf.reduce_max(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        y_pred = tf.logical_and(y_pred >= threshold, tf.abs(y_pred) > 1e-12)
        
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)
        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.bool)
        
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        self.true_positive.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values, axis=0))
        
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, False), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        self.false_positive.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values, axis=0)) 
        
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, False), tf.equal(y_pred, False))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        self.true_negative.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values, axis=0)) 
        
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, False))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        self.false_negative.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values, axis=0))
    
    def result(self):
        self.sensitivity.assign(tf.math.divide_no_nan(self.true_positive,tf.math.add(self.true_positive,self.false_negative)))
        return self.sensitivity[1]
    def get_config(self):
        """Returns the config"""
        config = {
            'num_classes':2
            }
        
        base_config = super().get_config()
        
        return {**base_config, **config}
    
    def reset_states(self):
        reset_value = tf.zeros(2, dtype=self.dtype)
        K.batch_set_value([(v, reset_value) for v in self.variables])
    
class MulticlassSpecificity(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name='Specificity', **kwargs):
        super(MulticlassSpecificity, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positive = self.add_weight(name='tp', shape=(2,), initializer='zeros')
        self.true_negative = self.add_weight(name='tn', shape=(2,), initializer='zeros')
        self.false_positive = self.add_weight(name='fp', shape=(2,), initializer='zeros')
        self.false_negative = self.add_weight(name='fn', shape=(2,), initializer='zeros')
        self.specificity = self.add_weight(name='specificity', shape=(2,), initializer='zeros')
        
        self.true_class = tf.Variable([False, True])
        self.false_class = tf.Variable([True, False])
        
    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        threshold = tf.reduce_max(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        y_pred = tf.logical_and(y_pred >= threshold, tf.abs(y_pred) > 1e-12)
        
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)
        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.bool)
        
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        self.true_positive.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values, axis=0))
        
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, False), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        self.false_positive.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values, axis=0)) 
        
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, False), tf.equal(y_pred, False))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        self.true_negative.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values, axis=0)) 
        
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, False))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        self.false_negative.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values, axis=0))
        
    def result(self):
        self.specificity.assign(tf.math.divide_no_nan(self.true_negative,tf.math.add(self.true_negative, self.false_positive)))
        return self.specificity[1]
    
    def get_config(self):
        """Returns the config"""
        config = {
            'num_classes':2
            }
        
        base_config = super().get_config()
        
        return {**base_config, **config}
    
    def reset_states(self):
        reset_value = tf.zeros(2, dtype=self.dtype)
        K.batch_set_value([(v, reset_value) for v in self.variables])
```

when I evaluate the model using `model.evaluate()`, this is what I get:

Test on test set:
86/86 [==============================] - 6s 59ms/step - loss: 0.2944 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4465 - f1_score: 0.4415 - Specificity: 0.2740 - Sensitivity: 0.8057

[0.29457294940948486,
0.4528070390224457,
array([0.4514866 , 0.45412117], dtype=float32),
0.33382710814476013,
0.6994695663452148]

Answer (score 0):

when invoking evaluate, pass return_dict=True.
Evaluate will return a label for each value and you will know what they are.

Something like:

```
print(m.evaluate(x,y,return_dict=True))
```

Comment: From the values, I can guess they're in the same order as printed, but what I'm asking is if this is the case, then why the last two values are so different?

Comment: you did not provide the whole code so i'm a bit confused. You have used fit() to first train your model and now you are using evaluate(). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I've trained my model using ```model.fit()``` and after that used ```model.evaluate()``` to test it!